# Regexp in Ant does not find anything

Tags: ant

I need to replace a string in a html page.
But I can't get my regexp to find the string.

I have this line:

<span class="foobar">Random text</span>

And I want to change it to this instead:

<span class="foobar">New text</span>

I have tried various variants of this example without match.

```
<replace file="${install.path}\app_data\Header.htm">
      <replacefilter token="foobar&quot;&gt;.*" value="foobar&quot;&gt; New text &lt;/span&gt;" />
</replace>
```

What am I missing? When I test the regex in a regex tool it looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And just as I had posted this, I found the answer:

```
<replaceregexp match="foobar&quot;&gt;(.*)&lt;" replace=foobar&quot;&gt; New text &lt;">
    <fileset dir="${install.path}\app_data" includes="Header.htm"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Comment: That's nice, but you do know that this causes problems if you have more than one `&lt;` on a matching line in your source code? `.*` blindly matches across everything, irrespective of tag boundaries etc., which is one of the many reasons that regular expressions are usually not the tool of choice for dealing with markup languages like HTML.

Comment: Yes I know. But in this case it is a simple one liner. But on the other hand, I will take your advice and tweak the expression a bit so it is a bit safer.